# Identical Content But JUnit Test Fails(IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, system-rules

I have a JUnit Test that compares two strings:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule log = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Autowired
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }

    @Test
    public void play() {
        player.play();
        assertEquals("Playing title Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band by artist The Beatles\n",
                log.getLog());
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `org.junit.ComparisonFailure` exception on the second test. However, IntelliJ shows contents are identical. What am I missing?

EDIT: Added back the \n at the end of the expected string.

[image]

Comment: Use `log.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator()` in order to avoid problems with system dependent line encodings.

Comment: Thanks, that worked beautifully!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a `log.getLog().trim()` and removing the \n from the end of your expected string.

Comment: Did but same error. The Expected is from `System.out.println("")`, so the `\n` is there but where is the CR coming from?

Comment: @Rajkishan I was just editing my answer when I got your response :-P. Yes, you'll have to remove the `\n` from the expected string for the comparison to work.

Answer (score 5):

You have different end line sign (LF vs CRLF)